# Program Displays the number of Mersenne wrong

Tags: java

hi guys the problem that im having with this code is that the number of mersenne primes is supposed to be 4 but it outputs 8. i know this because the number of Mersenne primes between 1 and 1000 are 3, 7, 31, and 127 but it also outputs 15, 63, 255, and 511. which i dont know why. is there also a way to output the counts of Primes per 100 numbers? thanks

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Prime numbers between 1 and 1000 are\n");
    String message = "";
    String message2 = "";
    // loop numbers from 1 to 1,000, printing only the primes
            int counter2 = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            for( int number s= 2; number <= 1000; number ++){               
               if(isPrime(number)) {
                  counter++;                     
                  if(counter % 10 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(number);
                  }
                  else
                    System.out.print(number + " ");
                 }
               }             
         for(int number2 = 2; number2 <= 1000; number2 ++){        
           if(isMersenne(number2)){             
                 counter2++;
                 System.out.print(number2 + "*");
              }             
            }
            System.out.print( "\n\n The number of primes between 1 and 1000 are " + counter);
            System.out.print( "\n The number of Mersennes is " + counter2);                 
 }

public static boolean isPrime( int number ){
            // initialize the boolean variable prime to true
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for(int divisor = 2; divisor <= number /2; divisor++) {
             if(number % divisor == 0) {
              isPrime = false;
             }     
           }
            return isPrime;
         }

public static boolean isMersenne(int number){           
                // declare and initialize variable powTwo to 2
                int powTwo = 2;
                boolean mersenne = false;
                    while(powTwo <= number){
                          powTwo *= 2;
                       if(powTwo - number == 1)                
                       // if the prime is one less than a power of 2, return true
                       mersenne =  true;
                    }              
        return mersenne;    
            } // end method isMersenne
       }
```

this is the output of my program

```
 Prime numbers between 1 and 1000 are

 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71
 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113
 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173
 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229
 233 239 241 251 257 263 269 271 277 281
 283 293 307 311 313 317 331 337 347 349
 353 359 367 373 379 383 389 397 401 409
 419 421 431 433 439 443 449 457 461 463
 467 479 487 491 499 503 509 521 523 541
 547 557 563 569 571 577 587 593 599 601
 607 613 617 619 631 641 643 647 653 659
 661 673 677 683 691 701 709 719 727 733
 739 743 751 757 761 769 773 787 797 809
 811 821 823 827 829 839 853 857 859 863
 877 881 883 887 907 911 919 929 937 941
 947 953 967 971 977 983 991 997 3*7*15*31*63*127*255*511*

 The number of primes between 1 and 1000 are 168
 The number of Mersennes is 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `isMersenne` is just checking whether the number is one less than a power of two.  It's not also checking that it's a prime.

You need to change your `isMersenne` method so that it calls `isPrime` after checking whether the number is one less than a power of two.  If `isPrime` returns false, then `isMersenne` should also return false.